# JSON schema that validates if patternProperties matches one of the value

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Given this schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^(.*)$": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^.*$": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": ["Token1", "Token2", "Token3"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to validate this sort of data:

```
{
  "myobject": {
    "prop1": "Token1",
    "prop2": "Token2",
    "prop3": "Token3"
  },
  "anotherobject": {
    "otherprop1": "Token1",
    "otherprop2": "Token3"
  }
}
```

i.e. each value of property under top-level object should be in `["Token1", "Token2", "Token3"]` enum. If I set `Token4` as value, it fails the validation as expected.

Is it possible to match the value of capturing group `^(.*)$` pattern and add another rule under `oneOf` that implies: OR the value is in set of (top-level) object names? To validate something like this successfully:

```
{
  "myobject": {
    "prop1": "Token1",
    "prop2": "Token2",
    "prop3": "Token3"
  },
  "anotherobject": {
    "otherprop1": "myobject",    <- note this
    "otherprop2": "Token3"
  }
}
```

but fails at

```
{
  "myobject": {
    "prop1": "Token1",
    "prop2": "Token2",
    "prop3": "Token3"
  },
  "anotherobject": {
    "otherprop1": "non-existing-object",    <- note this
    "otherprop2": "Token3"
  }
}
```

and preferably/optionally checks basic recursion to fail this input as well:

```
{
  "myobject": {
    "prop1": "Token1",
    "prop2": "Token2",
    "prop3": "Token3"
  },
  "anotherobject": {
    "otherprop1": "anotherobject",    <- note this
    "otherprop2": "Token3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with JSON Schema. Its domain is structural validation; rules like you describe can be implemented in code. Some validators allow custom keywords though.

By the way, you could use additionalProperties keyword to apply a schema to ALL properties.

Comment: Would it be terribly out of scope of schema to allow capturing group in `patternProperties` and let us refer it through `\1` for example?

Comment: Also, can you please show the code how would you simplify the given schema using `additionalProperties`?

Comment: That can be proposed to JSON Schema org, but I don’t think it’s likely to be accepted.

Comment: When “properties” keyword is absent, `patternProperties:{'^.*$': schema}` is equivalent to `additionalProperties: schema`